# Headphones doesn't give sound when lid is closed and opened

Tags: sound, suspend, headphones, lid

My laptop stopped giving sound from headphones when lid is closed and opened. After running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2
sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2
killall pulseaudio
rm -r ~/.pulse*
ubuntu-support-status
sudo usermod -aG `cat /etc/group | grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g'` `whoami`
```

and shutting it down, then rebooting without headphones works but I think there must be an easier way to avoid the situation. Any advice and explanation is appreciated.

Note: I don't see any difference in alsamixer or pavucontrol on both of the situations. The code I found was recommended as a last option however I remember where I found it. (Most likely from Ubuntu Wiki) 
My laptop is custom built however I can post any outcome you want.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new here :). Is there any way I could message you?

Answer (score 0):

Then you "close and open" the lid, the system invokes a suspend/hibernate on your behalf. See `man pm-action`. The scripts in `/etc/pm/config.d` hold the configuration, and `/etc/pm/sleep.d`, `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d` hold scripts that are run both at "suspend/hibernate" and "resume/thaw" times to first save, then restore hardware states that don't survive the process.

This is the software mechanism that should save and restore the headphone state. Look at `/var/log/pm-suspend.log`.

Comment: There is no pm-suspend-log in log folder. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Typo? Look at `/var/log/pm-*.log`. Note: "`pm-suspend-log` in log folder" and `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` are not the same.

Comment: There is no file starting with pm in /var/log.